# Pass Scala Seq into Scala function from Java

Tags: java, scala, collections, seq

I have been smacking my head against the table for hours. I am trying to call a function that is written in a library that takes `Seq<Object>` as the only argument type. The problem is, I can't seem to be able to construct anything that Scala wants to recognize as a collection type.

I've tried everything from using Scala Buffers and the like and trying to convert to a Seq or using the `$colon$colon` stuff. Nothing works can someone please point me in the right direction.

EDIT:

This is the code I'm using at the moment

```
    List<Object> objs = new ArrayList<>();

    Object obj = new Object();
    objs.add(obj);   

    function(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(objs));
```

Which has no errors but I receive `java.lang.String cannot be cast to [B`

I omitted some arguments to `new Object()` since it is sensitive data

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.lang.String cannot be cast to [B` means you're trying to pass a `String` to a method that calls for a `byte[]` (that's what `[B` means).

Try calling [`getBytes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)) on your `String` and that should fix your problem.

*(Note: It appears your problem has nothing to do with the code you posted. Maybe it's in the "sensitive" part that you removed.)*